# I need to allow nulls when I programmatically bind a textbox

Tags: vb.net, data-binding

I was thinking I should just change the value to "" when a null value has been read from the datasoure. But then I thought maybe there is a property that allows this. is there?

```
txtComments.DataBindings.Add("Text", rowEquipItem, "Comment")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Binding.Format` event ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.format.aspx)):

```
Private Sub AddBinding
    Dim b As Binding = New Binding("Text", rowEquipItem, "Comment")
    AddHandler b.Format, AddressOf nullToEmpty
    txtComments.DataBindings.Add(b)
End Sub    

Private Sub nullToEmpty(sender As Object, e As ConvertEventArgs)
    If e.DesiredType IsNot GetType(String) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If IsDBNull(e.Value) Then        
        e.Value = ""
    End If
End Sub
```